# Can not debug node.js locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, local

I wrote a simple script:

```
var a = 7;
var b = a + 2;
var c = b;
```

I put the above script in a file `foo.js`.

Now I open **Git Bash** in the same with `foo.js` folder and run the following command:

> node --inspect foo.js

Here is what I am getting:

> $ node --inspect foo.js
>
> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/185f8862-17db-44d5-aff0-03c8e6fd50df
>
> For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

Then I go to `chrome://inspect/`, then to `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`.

Here is what I see:
[image]

I do not see my code for run or debug. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your case, but since it seems like you are using Visual Code, I recommend you to use the in build Node.js debugger. Here are the steps to follow in order to configure it https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging.

Newer version of Visual Code will automatically configure the debugger and you just have to set the breakpoints and press the debugger button or F5, keep in mind that it will create a launch.json in your root project folder .vscode>launch.json

Answer (score 1):

1. `node --inspect-brk foo.js.`
2. Move to Chrome and enter `chrome://inspect` in the tab
3. Move to `device-->Remote` `Target-->foo.js-->`Click `inspect`
4. In the new window, on the left tab, click **Add folder to Workspace** and select the folder containing the file foo.js

Now you can debug the file.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at protocol. It's not a http connection (which you're connecting on) but WebSocket. This is mostly for IDEs to handle debugging such as VSCode.

Btw. VSCode has native support for debugging Node.js, just write some app and press F5

Answer (score 0):

Try to open inspector tools, instead, from "Remote Target" section from this page:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

- Old way yet also available - *open tab with url*:

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/{{YOUR_KEY}}
```